# Cant install rails 4.0 using rubyinstaller. *** extconf.rb failed ***

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to install ruby on rails (v4.0) using ruby installer. It is throwing me this error. I am brand new to RoR and some websites told me to install devkit. I have done that. I ran *gem install thin*

```
 C:\Users\shashid\Downloads>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RubyRails/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RubyRails/bin/ruby
        --with-atomic_reference-dir
        --without-atomic_reference-dir
        --with-atomic_reference-include
        --without-atomic_reference-include=${atomic_reference-dir}/include
        --with-atomic_reference-lib
        --without-atomic_reference-lib=${atomic_reference-dir}/
C:/RubyRails/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do': The compiler failed to gene
rate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/RubyRails/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:516:in `try_link0'
        from C:/RubyRails/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:814:in `try_run'
        from extconf.rb:22:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RubyRails/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-
1.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RubyRails/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_ma
ke.out
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: what's the contents of C:/RubyRails/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out (my guess is your devkit isn't installed quite right...)

Comment: sorry for late reply. But, something happened and my installation of ROR was completely messed up. I had to uninstall ror and install it from scratch. and, this is because the 64bit rails wasnt working on my 64bit machine. I installed the 32bit version and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Ruby DevKit if on windows, get it from: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ (scroll down a little).

Answer (score 0):

Same story here deleting ruby and installing:

- Ruby 2.0.0-p247
- DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe

from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ solved the problem.

Comment: Looks like there might be some problem with installing on 64-bit Windows... I ended up going with Rails Installer (although its only Ruby 1.9.3 at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use railsinstaller from http://railsinstaller.org/
it will install follwing

```
Ruby 1.9.3-p392
Rails 4
Bundler
Git
Sqlite
TinyTDS
SQL Server Support
DevKit
```

Answer (score 0):

The same can happen when you try to combine 32-bit Ruby and 64-bit DevKit.
The solution is to use same-bit versions.

For instance current versions:
rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p247-x64.exe
DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe